# difference between array and pointer notation of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{

 char heart[]="I Love Tillie"; /* using array notation */

 int i;
 for (i=0;i<6;i++)
 {
   printf("%c",&heart[i]);  /* %c expects the address of the character we want to print     */
 }

 return 0;
```

}

If `heart[i]` and `&heart[i]` mean the same thing , which is the address of `heart[i]`, why is my program giving me this-`??????`, as output? Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: Where did you read `heart[i]` is same as `&heart[i]` ?

Comment: They don't mean the same thing.

Comment: The name of a character array, like any array name, yields the address of the first element of
the array. Therefore, the following holds for the array m1:
m1 == &m1[0] , *m1 == 'L', and *(m1+1) == m1[1] == 'i' from C Primer Plus- STephen Prata , confused me too.

Comment: What gave you the idea that a `char` is the same as the address of a char (`char *`)?! [I've explained this in an answer to one of your other questions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20633665/1230836), didn't I?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: I get it now, pointers are a tad bit confusing. Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: Check this too http://boredzo.org/pointers/#arrays

Comment: You have misread the equivalences. Apparently, the array is `char m1[] = "Like";` or something similar.  Saying that `m1 == &m1[0]` is accurate.  Saying that `*m1 == 'L'` is equivalent to saying `m1[0] == 'L'` and given the initialization I showed is accurate. Similarly, `*(m1+1) == 'i'` and `m1[1] == 'i'` are individually accurate, but the composite statement `*(m1+1) == m1[1] == 'i'` does not evaluate to true in C, though it makes sense speaking loosely.

Comment: @sidchelseafan: If you're having a hard time understanding pointers [check my explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114400/print-a-number-in-c-digit-by-digit/20114877#20114877). I compare pointers to a calendar, it seemed t clear a lot of things up for some people

Comment: @sidchelseafan: "The name of a character array, like any array name, yields the address of the first element of the array. " It is converted to a pointer value *in some contexts*.

Answer (score 4):

First of all

should be

```
printf("%c",heart[i]); // if you want to print the charachter
```

or

```
printf("%p",&heart[i]); // if you want to print the charachter address in the memory
```

and not

```
printf("%c",&heart[i])
```

The `heart` is an array of charachters and the `heart[i]` is the charachter number `i` in the array

The `&heart[i]` is the memory address of the element number `i` in the `heart` array. and to print the memory address you have to use `"%p"`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print an address as a single character; this is bad news.

`heart[i]` is a single character; `&heart[i]` is the address of that character.  They are not the same thing at all.

Try a loop like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
     printf("%c", heart[i]);
     printf(": %s\n", &heart[i]);
}
```

See what a difference the different conversion specifications (and parameter types) make.  If you wish, you can add a `printf("%p ", (void *)&heart[i]);` to the start of the loop to see how the address values change as you go through the loop.

Comment: Yes, `%p` would work; it would do a completely different job, of course.  `%p` will print the address; `%s` will print the substring.  Of the two, the substring is probably more interesting to the OP, but you could add a `printf("%p\n", (void *)&heart[i]);` to the list of informative printing operations.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: `%p` would also require a `(void *)` cast